# What am I doing wrong with setting up ITK library for Qt Creator using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, itk

I have tried both:

1. I built ITK-library using CMake and then linked my HelloWorld.cxx manually in the .pro file as shown here:

---

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib"

LIBS += /folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib/
-libITKBiasCorrection-4.7/
-libITKBioCell-4.7/
-libITKCommon-4.7/
-libitkdouble-conversion-4.7/
-libITKDICOMParser-4.7/
etc.
```

However when I build this in Qt Creator it does not recognize `#include "itkImage.h"` and thus does not compile...

2. I wrote an CMakeLists.txt files and called it in Qt Creator using File > Open File or Project. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

---

```
PROJECT(HelloWorld)
FIND_PACKAGE (ITK REQUIRED)
IF (ITK_FOUND)
INCLUDE( ${ITK_USE_FILE} )
ENDIF(ITK_FOUND)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cxx)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (HelloWorld /folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib)
```

My HelloWorld.cxx looks as follows (from a given example from www.itk.org):

```
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageFileReader.h"
#include "itkGradientMagnitudeImageFilter.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv) {

typedef itk::Image <unsigned short,2> ImageType;
typedef itk::ImageFileReader <ImageType> ReaderType;
typedef itk::GradientMagnitudeImageFilter <ImageType,ImageType> FilterType;

ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New();
FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New();

reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
filter->SetInput(reader->GetOutput() );
filter->Update();

return 0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += "/folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib"` Are you sure that `itkImage.h` in this folder? Usually h-files are in `include` folder. `LIBS += /folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib/` Here you use directory instead of lib file.

Comment: `/folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build/lib` in this folder only are a lot of .a files. I have searched through all folders, there is no `include` folder in `ITK-build` folder. What do you mean with directory instead of lib file? Lib is a directory that contains .a files. Thx.

Comment: Search for `itkImage.h` I don't know where it is, if it is in lib folder, your INCLUDEPATH parameter is OK. Regarding LIBS - it should contain library names and not folders.

Comment: I used `find . ".h"` in my `/folder1/folder2/folder3/ITK-build` folder. There is not a single .h file. I don't understand this.

Comment: `ITK-build` looks like a build folder that contains only makefiles. ITK source files should be somewhere else, you should know where they are. Probably n your secret folder1, folder2...foldern. Or in one of system-wide include folders, if ITK headers were installed.

Comment: I searched in all folders but nowhere I can find this `itkImage.h`. I am really desperate - its not like a math problem you can clearly see the path, its just I don't know further. I'm googling for hours without success. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but...

You are saying no `include` inside the `ITK-build` folder and that you are just trying to grab whats inside the `build` folder. Check if ITK has a `make install` (I'm not familiar with ITK but I have successfully built and installed VTK by Kitware who currently manages both ITK and CMake). Otherwise you will have to do a combo between the sources and built folders to get all that you need.

In most cases it's the installation step that creates the final "image" of the software that you use in your own projects. This step copies library files, executables (usually examples and/or tests), headers etc. to the installation path. In case of ITK it also should place the required `cmake` modules so that you can actually use `find_package(ITK)`. Some developers prefer to copy the required headers first to the build folder and then to the installation path. There isn't a "standard" way of doing this.

I also suggest to output some message inside the `if`-check

```
IF (ITK_FOUND)
message("ITK here!!!")
INCLUDE( ${ITK_USE_FILE} )
ENDIF(ITK_FOUND)
```

in order to see if the `include(...)` is executed at all. My guess would be that it's not.